# sticky div stuck in row

Tags: html, css

I'm using bootstrap 3.
What I'm trying to do in .cshtml create a 'sticky div'
what I've tried until this time https://jsfiddle.net/r41vunwb/
I don't understand why the sticky part doesn't pass to the next row.

here is my minimized code part

```css
div.sticky {
  position: sticky !important;
  top: 0;
  align-self: flex-start;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row" style="text-align-last:center">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4" style="border-style:groove; border-bottom-style:none;">
            <div class="sticky" style="font-weight:bold; font-size:20px; background-color:#c9e8ff"> AAAAAA </div>
            <div style="border-top:groove">
                <p style="margin-bottom:-5px; font-weight:bold;">Ratio1</p>
            </div>
            <div id="chartdivE_i" style="min-height:400px"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="text-align-last:center">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4" style="border-style:groove; border-top-style:none; border-bottom-style:none;">
            <div style="border-top:groove">
                <p style="margin-bottom:-5px; font-weight:bold;">Ratio2</p>
            </div>
            <div id="chartdivK_i" style="min-height:400px"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="text-align-last:center">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4" style="border-style:groove; border-top-style:none; border-bottom-style:none;">
            <div style="border-top:groove">
                <p style="margin-bottom:-5px; font-weight:bold;">Ratio3</p>
            </div>
            <div id="chartdivT_i" style="min-height:400px"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="text-align-last:center">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4" style="border-style:groove; border-top-style:none;">
          <div style="border-top:groove">
              <p style="margin-bottom:-5px; font-weight:bold;">Ratio4</p>
          </div>
          <div id="chartdivP_i" style="min-height:400px"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

thank you for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your sticky div is inside the first row. Move it up under the `panel-body`: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s7efqhr1/)

```css
div.sticky {
  position: sticky !important;
  top: 0;
  align-self: flex-start;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="sticky" style="font-weight:bold; font-size:20px; background-color:#c9e8ff"> AAAAAA </div>
      <div class="row" style="text-align-last:center">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4" style="border-style:groove; border-bottom-style:none;">
              <div style="border-top:groove">
                  <p style="margin-bottom:-5px; font-weight:bold;">Ratio1</p>
              </div>
              <div id="chartdivE_i" style="min-height:400px"></div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" style="text-align-last:center">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4" style="border-style:groove; border-top-style:none; border-bottom-style:none;">
              <div style="border-top:groove">
                  <p style="margin-bottom:-5px; font-weight:bold;">Ratio2</p>
              </div>
              <div id="chartdivK_i" style="min-height:400px"></div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" style="text-align-last:center">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4" style="border-style:groove; border-top-style:none; border-bottom-style:none;">
              <div style="border-top:groove">
                  <p style="margin-bottom:-5px; font-weight:bold;">Ratio3</p>
              </div>
              <div id="chartdivT_i" style="min-height:400px"></div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" style="text-align-last:center">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4" style="border-style:groove; border-top-style:none;">
            <div style="border-top:groove">
                <p style="margin-bottom:-5px; font-weight:bold;">Ratio4</p>
            </div>
            <div id="chartdivP_i" style="min-height:400px"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: it has to be in row. is there any way? thx for answer

Comment: *it has to be in row* Then it can't be sticky for other rows. There is no other way. You probably need to change your design then